# Mixins or Multiple Inheritance in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview, abstract-class

Let's say for example that I have `MyUITextViewSubclass` which inherits from `UITextView` and `MyUITextFieldSubclass` which inherits from `UITextField` and both of those subclasses contain a lot of the same methods and properties to add similar behavior to those UI controls.

Since `UITextView` and `UITextField` inherit from different classes, is there an easy way to create an abstract class to combine all of that repeated code?  **In other words, is it possible to create an abstract class that I could inherit from for both of those subclasses and then just override the methods that are different between the two?**

What I know so far:

- I know Objective-C doesn't support multiple inheritance (inheritance from two or more classes)
- I know I could add common methods using Categories, but I don't think that solves overriding init methods or adding private properties

Comment: could you be more specific about what the common behavior is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Building on Amin's answer, this is how you could do it:

**Step 1:** Create a `TextSurrogateHosting` protocol that will contain all the methods of your `UITextField` and `UITextView` subclasses that you need to access from the methods that you want to add to both subclasses. This might for example be a `text` and `setText:` method, so that your methods can access and set the text of either a text field or a text view. It might look like this:

***SPWKTextSurrogateHosting.h***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol SPWKTextSurrogateHosting <NSObject>

- (NSString *)text;
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text;

@end
```

**Step 2:** Create a `TextSurrogate` class that contains all the methods that you want to share between both the `UITextField` and the `UITextView` subclasses. Add those methods to a protocol so that we can use code completion in Xcode and avoid compiler warnings/errors.

***SPWKTextSurrogate.h***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SPWKTextSurrogateHosting.h"

@protocol SPWKTextSurrogating <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)appendQuestionMark;
- (void)appendWord:(NSString *)aWord;
- (NSInteger)characterCount;
- (void)capitalize;
@end

@interface SPWKTextSurrogate : NSObject <SPWKTextSurrogating>

/* We need to init with a "host", either a UITextField or UITextView subclass */
- (id)initWithHost:(id<SPWKTextSurrogateHosting>)aHost;

@end
```

***SPWKTextSurrogate.m***

```
#import "SPWKTextSurrogate.h"

@implementation SPWKTextSurrogate {
    id<SPWKTextSurrogateHosting> _host;
}

- (id)initWithHost:(id<SPWKTextSurrogateHosting>)aHost
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _host = aHost;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)appendQuestionMark
{
    _host.text = [_host.text stringByAppendingString:@"?"];
}

- (void)appendWord:(NSString *)aWord
{
    _host.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", _host.text, aWord];
}

- (NSInteger)characterCount
{
    return [_host.text length];
}

- (void)capitalize
{
    _host.text = [_host.text capitalizedString];
}

@end
```

**Step 3:** Create your `UITextField` subclass. It will contain three necessary boilerplate methods to forward unrecognized method invocations to your `SPWKTextSurrogate`.

***SPWKTextField.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SPWKTextSurrogateHosting.h"
#import "SPWKTextSurrogate.h"

@interface SPWKTextField : UITextField <SPWKTextSurrogateHosting, SPWKTextSurrogating>

@end
```

***SPWKTextField.m***

```
#import "SPWKTextField.h"

@implementation SPWKTextField {
    SPWKTextSurrogate *_surrogate;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _surrogate = [[SPWKTextSurrogate alloc] initWithHost:self];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark Invocation Forwarding
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    if ([_surrogate respondsToSelector:[anInvocation selector]]) {
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:_surrogate];
    } else {
        [super forwardInvocation:anInvocation];
    }
}

- (NSMethodSignature*)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    NSMethodSignature* signature = [super methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    if (!signature) {
        signature = [_surrogate methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    }
    return signature;
}

- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    if ([super respondsToSelector:aSelector] ||
        [_surrogate respondsToSelector:aSelector])
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

**Step 4:** Create your `UITextView` subclass.

***SPWKTextView.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SPWKTextSurrogateHosting.h"
#import "SPWKTextSurrogate.h"

@interface SPWKTextView : UITextView <SPWKTextSurrogateHosting, SPWKTextSurrogating>

@end
```

***SPWKTextView.m***

```
#import "SPWKTextView.h"
#import "SPWKTextSurrogate.h"

@implementation SPWKTextView {
    SPWKTextSurrogate *_surrogate;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _surrogate = [[SPWKTextSurrogate alloc] initWithHost:self];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark Invocation Forwarding
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    if ([_surrogate respondsToSelector:[anInvocation selector]]) {
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:_surrogate];
    } else {
        [super forwardInvocation:anInvocation];
    }
}

- (NSMethodSignature*)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    NSMethodSignature* signature = [super methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    if (!signature) {
        signature = [_surrogate methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    }
    return signature;
}

- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    if ([super respondsToSelector:aSelector] ||
        [_surrogate respondsToSelector:aSelector])
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

**Step 5:** Use it:

```
SPWKTextField *textField = [[SPWKTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
SPWKTextView *textView = [[SPWKTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

textField.text = @"The green fields";
textView.text = @"What a wonderful view";

[textField capitalize];
[textField appendWord:@"are"];
[textField appendWord:@"green"];
[textField appendQuestionMark];

NSLog(@"textField.text: %@", textField.text);
// Output: The Green Fields are green?

[textView capitalize];
[textView appendWord:@"this"];
[textView appendWord:@"is"];

NSLog(@"textView.text: %@", textView.text);
// Output: What A Wonderful View this is
```

This pattern should solve your problem. Hopefully :)

Some more background information is available here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH105

Comment: Definitely an interesting approach!  This solves most of the issues with my original approach.  Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a mixin. This is not supported in Objective-C. Categories are no mixins, because they add an api to *one* class not to *many* (>1) classes. Using categories, what is not possible for many reasons as you said, would not help you.

The usual way to solve that problem is to create a helper class containing the additional code and use it in both classes.

Then you will find yourself typing

```
[myUITextViewSubclass.helper doSomething]
```

instead of

```
[myUITextViewSubclass doSomething]
```

If this is really a problem, you can solve this with forward invocations. Just write a comment.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible.

The closest thing you could achieve would be to manually add functionality to `UITextView` to make it mimic `UITextField`. The obvious downside is that you must do this all manually, with your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a preprocessor macro, but that is error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Traits or Mixins are not supported by Objective-C, you only have built-in option of Categories.
But fortunately Objective-C Runtime has almost all tools for implementing own idea if mixing or traits with adding methods and properties to your class at runtime. You can read more about opportunities which Objective-C Runtime provides for you on Apple's documentation website [Objective-C Runtime Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/objective_c_runtime)

**The idea is:**

1) You can create an Objective-C protocol (Mixin), in which you will declare properties and methods.

2) Then you create a class (Mixin implementation), which will implement methods from this protocol.

3) You make your some class, in which you want to provide the possibility of composition with mixins, to conform that protocol (Mixin).

4) When your application launches, you add with Objective-C runtime all implementations from (Mixin implementation) class and properties declared in (Mixin) into your class.

5) voilà :)

***Or you can use some ready open source projects such as "[Alchemiq](https://github.com/iaagg/Alchemiq)"***